# nextToken() not consuming token from stream?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am able to generate the following RuntimeException and am unsure why. My understanding is that nextToken() advances the underlying stream.  The offending token is a normal token in the middle of a document I am parsing, not something strange like EOF.

```
class TokenStreamRelease implements TokenStream
{
    private final MyLexer _lexer; // MyLexer extends org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer

    Token _nextToken;

    @Override
    public Token next()
    {
        Token toReturn = _nextToken;
        _nextToken = _lexer.nextToken();
        if(_nextToken == _lexer.getToken())
        {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code basically says: if the current token is equal to the current token, throw a `RuntimeException`.

[`Lexer.getToken`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/3bdc4b7ee64623c5675fb16855ccdec9073e2888/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Lexer.java#L325) is defined as:

```
public Token getToken() { return _token; }
```

And `Lexer.nextToken` updates and [returns `_token`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/3bdc4b7ee64623c5675fb16855ccdec9073e2888/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Lexer.java#L181).

So calling `getToken` right after `nextToken` will get you the same token as a result.